Does qubitization work for non-hermitian matrices?
In the original qubitization paper, Definition 2 for a quantum signal processor requires a Hermitian matrix with bounded spectral norm. However, lemmas 8 and 10 are extended to normal matrices in Appendix A. Does this mean we can use quantum signal processing for any normal matrix? I.e. do Theorems 3 and 4 hold for normal matrices?

Essentially, yes. However note that the conditions of Theorem 3 and 4 are stated in the context of transforming real eigenvalues via the polynomials $A, B, C$. A normal matrix generally has complex eigenvalues, and a polynomial normalized on $[-1, 1]$ is not necessarily normalized on the unit complex disk. The appropriate generalization is called the quantum singular value transformation, which applies to any matrix, even non-normal ones (because every matrix has an SVD). This tutorial may also be helpful.
